# Modify setting in web.config on TFS build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Is it possible to modify a web.config file in one of my projects during a Team Foundation Server build? Inside of my web.config file I have two setting keys: `VersionNumber` and `BuildNumber`.

Is it possible to change the value of `BuildNumber` based on the ID of the build in TFS?

Comment: What do you want to put into the Build Number?

Comment: @DaveShaw the ID of the TFS build. For example: Whenever you kick off a TFS build, it has a build ID. The last build I ran had an ID of 6030.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using TFS 2013 you have an easier option than the old way of modifying the workflow - Use PowerShell.

If you're using the build template TfvcTemplate.12.xaml (which is the new default in TFS 2013), then you have some extra build definition parameters you can set to specify Powershell scripts to run.  This way you just write a little bit of powershell code that gets the TFS Build Number (from an environment variable), then finds your web.config file(s) and changes them.

There is a sample script published in the TFS Community Build Extensions project that will do something very similar that you could modify.  It finds all AssemblyInfo.cs files, then uses RegEx to modify them to update the build number based on the TFS Build number.

See the sample PS script here: https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Scripts/ApplyVersionToAssemblies.ps1

See some docs on how to modify the build to run PowerShell here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I'm happy to hear this is integrated now.  I had written my own powershell runner for 2012.

Comment: Why did you write your own? This has been part of the TFS Community Build Tools for years. http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, though it's non-trivial.  I've done this in the past using two methods.

**Method 1**: Use CodeActivities and alter the TFS Build workflow XAML file to include the new CodeActivity as a workflow step.

Here's an article on creating custom workflows with custom code activities (it's a little dated but still relevant):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-create-a-custom-workflow-activity-for-tfs-build-2010.aspx

Basically, you create a new object that inherits from CodeActivity, create properties for your inputs (BuildNumber,VersionNumber, TargetFile), perform your actions on the TargetFile and save it.  Then you wire up this new DLL with your activity to the TFS Workflow XAML, injecting your activity in the desired build step (post-build & pre-package in your case I bet to ensure xml transforms are applied).

**Method 2**:
Tag the desired properties onto the MSBuild invocation inside the TFS XAML file so they are passed in to MSBuild and available for your to use as $(BuildNumber) and $(VersionNumber).  Then you can use MSBuild tasks to inject the properties into the file at the right time.